# In cpython source code, where does Python call the user defined __init__ when creating a class

Tags: init, cpython, python-internals

I am reading cpython source code class implementation, I knew the basic process of class definition and creation:

Class definition:

`LOAD_BUILD_CLASS -> builtin___build_class__ -> meta -> type_call -> type_new`

Class creation:

`type_call -> type_new`

And I knew the user defined functions are stored in the namespace and finally in the `tp_dict` of that type.

My question: User defined `__init__` function is stored in the `type->tp_dict`, when python initializes a type it calls `type->tp_init` function. I can not find where in cpython source code the user defined `__init__` function is called when initializing a class.

Answer (score 1):

Find the result by myself, type_new will call PyType_Ready and  fixup_slot_dispatchers, in later function user defined function will be handled in slots.